# Using Python need to convert the data from multiple columns to single column and repeat column A

Tags: python, csv, pandas, data-manipulation

Still I am pretty new to python, would need help in this :

The data I have is in csv format  like this :

```
   Month YEAR      AZ-Phoenix  CA-Los Angeles  CA-San Diego    CA-San Francisco    CO-Denver   DC-Washington
    January 1987            59.33       54.67       46.61           50.20
    February 1987           59.65       54.89       46.87           49.96       64.77
```

And this needs to be merged and displayed in column 2 and 3 by incrementing column 1 n.. times.

Output should be :

```
   Month YEAR                           
    January 1987    AZ-Phoenix
    January 1987    CA-Los Angeles      59.33
    January 1987    CA-San Diego        54.67
    January 1987    CA-San Francisco    46.61
    January 1987    CO-Denver       50.20
```

How can this be achieved in csv reader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with separator `tab` - `\t` or if separator is `2 and more whitespaces` use `piRSquared's` solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(sep='\t')
```

I think you need:

```
df = df.set_index('YEAR').stack(dropna=False).reset_index()
df.columns = ['YEAR','A','B']
print (df)
             YEAR                 A      B
0    January 1987        AZ-Phoenix  59.33
1    January 1987    CA-Los Angeles  54.67
2    January 1987            CA-San  46.61
3    January 1987             Diego  50.20
4    January 1987  CA-San Francisco    NaN
5    January 1987         CO-Denver    NaN
6    January 1987     DC-Washington    NaN
7   February 1987        AZ-Phoenix  59.65
8   February 1987    CA-Los Angeles  54.89
9   February 1987            CA-San  46.87
10  February 1987             Diego  49.96
11  February 1987  CA-San Francisco  64.77
12  February 1987         CO-Denver    NaN
13  February 1987     DC-Washington    NaN

#if need remove rows with NaN
df = df.set_index('YEAR').stack().reset_index()
df.columns = ['YEAR','A','B']
print (df)
            YEAR                 A      B
0   January 1987        AZ-Phoenix  59.33
1   January 1987    CA-Los Angeles  54.67
2   January 1987            CA-San  46.61
3   January 1987             Diego  50.20
4  February 1987        AZ-Phoenix  59.65
5  February 1987    CA-Los Angeles  54.89
6  February 1987            CA-San  46.87
7  February 1987             Diego  49.96
8  February 1987  CA-San Francisco  64.77
```

---

Another solution with [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html):

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='YEAR', value_name='B', var_name='A')
print (df)
             YEAR                 A      B
0    January 1987        AZ-Phoenix  59.33
1   February 1987        AZ-Phoenix  59.65
2    January 1987    CA-Los Angeles  54.67
3   February 1987    CA-Los Angeles  54.89
4    January 1987            CA-San  46.61
5   February 1987            CA-San  46.87
6    January 1987             Diego  50.20
7   February 1987             Diego  49.96
8    January 1987  CA-San Francisco    NaN
9   February 1987  CA-San Francisco  64.77
10   January 1987         CO-Denver    NaN
11  February 1987         CO-Denver    NaN
12   January 1987     DC-Washington    NaN
13  February 1987     DC-Washington    NaN


#if need remove rows with NaN
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='YEAR', value_name='B', var_name='A').dropna(subset=['B'])
print (df)
            YEAR                 A      B
0   January 1987        AZ-Phoenix  59.33
1  February 1987        AZ-Phoenix  59.65
2   January 1987    CA-Los Angeles  54.67
3  February 1987    CA-Los Angeles  54.89
4   January 1987            CA-San  46.61
5  February 1987            CA-San  46.87
6   January 1987             Diego  50.20
7  February 1987             Diego  49.96
9  February 1987  CA-San Francisco  64.77
```

Comment: Does df needs an import pandas statement? and Can this be used in csv reader?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Give me a some time

Comment: Glad can help you, nice day!

Comment: Now I am only on phone. I think tthe best is create new question with sample data, desired output and what you try. Good luck!

Comment: The January and 1987 are 2 different columns and when used the first code, it is salvaging the first row. i.e January is not displayed only the pivot happens on 1987, AZ-Phoenix, 59.33. How to make sure January is also considered.

Comment: Try add new column like `df = df.set_index(['YEAR', 'MONTH']).stack(dropna=False).reset_index()
df.columns = ['YEAR','MONTH','A','B']`

Answer (score 2):

***option 1***
use [`pd.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html)

```
pd.melt(df, 'YEAR')

             YEAR          variable  value
0    January 1987        AZ-Phoenix  59.33
1   February 1987        AZ-Phoenix  59.65
2    January 1987    CA-Los Angeles  54.67
3   February 1987    CA-Los Angeles  54.89
4    January 1987      CA-San Diego  46.61
5   February 1987      CA-San Diego  46.87
6    January 1987  CA-San Francisco  50.20
7   February 1987  CA-San Francisco  49.96
8    January 1987         CO-Denver    NaN
9   February 1987         CO-Denver  64.77
10   January 1987     DC-Washington    NaN
11  February 1987     DC-Washington    NaN
```

***option 2***
reconstruct with `numpy` tools

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(
        YEAR=df.YEAR.values.repeat(len(df.columns) - 1),
        B=df.drop('YEAR', 1).values.ravel(),
        A=np.tile(df.columns.difference(['YEAR']).values, len(df)),
    ))[['YEAR', 'A', 'B']]


             YEAR          variable  value
0    January 1987        AZ-Phoenix  59.33
1   February 1987        AZ-Phoenix  59.65
2    January 1987    CA-Los Angeles  54.67
3   February 1987    CA-Los Angeles  54.89
4    January 1987      CA-San Diego  46.61
5   February 1987      CA-San Diego  46.87
6    January 1987  CA-San Francisco  50.20
7   February 1987  CA-San Francisco  49.96
8    January 1987         CO-Denver    NaN
9   February 1987         CO-Denver  64.77
10   January 1987     DC-Washington    NaN
11  February 1987     DC-Washington    NaN
```

***setup***

```
df = pd.read_csv(sep='\s{2,}', engine='python')
```

Comment: The January and 1987 are 2 different columns and when used the first code, it is salvaging the first row. i.e January is not displayed only the pivot happens on 1987, AZ-Phoenix, 59.33. How to make sure January is also considered